# Vue js props value comes undefined

Tags: javascript, parameters, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I may be wrong in my understanding of props but I can't seem to be able to pass a prop to a component and retrieve its value since it always comes as undefined.

Route:

```
{
  path: '/account/:username',
  name: 'acccount',
  component: Account
},
```

Router-link to the component:

```
<router-link class="btn btn-warning margin-bottom-20" :to="{ name: 'acccount', params: {username: user.username}}">Edit</router-link>
```

Component:

```
export default {
  name: 'account',

  props: ['username'],

  computed: {
    user() {
      return this.$store.getters.getUser(this.username);
    }
  }
}
```

My /accounts view succefully changes to /account/{username} but once on the component the value this.username returns nothing but undefined.

[image: This is the vue devtools debugger:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your route:

```
{
  path: '/account/:username',
  name: 'acccount',
  component: Account
}
```

To:

```
{
  path: '/account/:username',
  name: 'acccount',
  component: Account,
  props: true
}
```